# Use of the 'hash' command

Tags: bash, hash, ffmpeg

I'm working on a small app based on ffmpeg, and I read a [tutorial made for ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1438052.html) where they advise to use the command `hash` on the produced executable.

I'm curious about that command, did you ever use it? For which purpose?

When I run it in my source folder, I get this (once compiled)

```
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/strip
   1    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
   1    /usr/bin/svn
   4    /usr/local/bin/brew
   2    /usr/bin/git
   1    /bin/rm
   1    /bin/cat
   1    /usr/bin/ld
   1    /bin/sh
   4    /usr/bin/man
   5    /usr/bin/make
   4    /usr/bin/otool
  15    /bin/ls
   6    /usr/bin/open
   2    /usr/bin/clear
```

Looks like a summary of my bash_history…

When I run it on an executable file, I do not have lots of lines displayed, and nothing seems to changes in that application ?

```
$ md5 ffserver
MD5 (ffserver) = 2beac612e5efd6ee4a827ae0893ee338
$ hash ffserver
$ md5 ffserver
MD5 (ffserver) = 2beac612e5efd6ee4a827ae0893ee338
```

When I look for the man, it just says it's a builtin function. Really useful :)

It does work (let say *exist*) on Linux and on [MacOSX](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923083736/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hash.1.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`hash` isn't actually your history; it is a `bash(1)` shell built-in that maintains a hash table of recently executed programs:

> Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files (see hash under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  A full search of the directories in PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table.

(From [`bash(1)`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/bash1.html).)

The guide your found may have suggested running it just to see *which* `ffmpeg` command was going to be executed by the next step; perhaps there is an `ffmpeg` program supplied by the distribution packaging, and they wanted to make sure the new one would be executed instead of the distro-supplied one if you just typed `ffmpeg` at the shell.

It seems a stretch, because it would *also* require having the directory containing the new `ffmpeg` in the `PATH` *before* the distro-provided version, and there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: Cool, thanks... I still don't get why i should use this after a compilation, because i usually do not compile in $PATH.

Comment: @Rob, agreed, it seems strange to me. I think I've _needed_ hash once in the fifteen or sixteen years I've been using Unix or Linux systems, and that might have just been due to my inexperience at the time.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: I am the main author of the mentioned tutorial and added the `hash` command (although it should be `hash -d ffmpeg`, not the `hash -r` shotgun approach). It was years ago, but if I recall correctly there was an uncommon corner-case encountered by some users where the distro `ffmpeg` was being executed instead of the newly compiled `ffmpeg` despite both being in the PATH. I don't remember the exact details and forgot how to reproduce the behavior (I recall it was easily reproducible), but issuing `hash` prevented/resolved it. I'll have to take a look at it again.

Comment: @llogan, I still prefer `hash -r`, since (a) it's less typing (b) re-learning the paths to the other commands isn't actually all that expensive.

Answer (score 9):

If you use commands that might not be installed on the system, check for their availability and tell the user what's missing. From [Scripting with style](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style)

Example:

```
NEEDED_COMMANDS="sed awk lsof who"

missing_counter=0
for needed_command in $NEEDED_COMMANDS; do
  if ! hash "$needed_command" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf "Command not found in PATH: %s\n" "$needed_command" >&2
    ((missing_counter++))
  fi
done

if ((missing_counter > 0)); then
  printf "Minimum %d commands are missing in PATH, aborting" "$missing_counter" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```